# Malfunctioning type-casting of string to unsigned int

Tags: c++, validation, casting

I'm having a annoying problem with a C++ function that I wrote and whose purpose is to validate de user input. The function reads the user input, verifies if it's a number and, if so, if it is in the range [min, max].

The problem occurs when I invoke the template function with a unsigned type, like `size_t`, and the input is a negative number. The string stream converts the string to something like 4294967291. I can see that the program is converting the data to a value near de maximum value of the unsigned data type (defined in the numeric_limits header) but my question is why, since the `if` statement should stop at `sstream >> value`?

My code:

```
template <class T>
T getNumberInput(std::string prompt, T min, T max) {
    std::string input;
    T value;

    while (true) {
        try {
            std::cout << prompt;
            std::cin.clear();
            std::getline(std::cin, input);
            std::stringstream sstream(input);

            if (input.empty()) {
                throw EmptyInput<std::string>(input);
            } else if (sstream >> value && value >= min && value <= max) {
                std::cout << std::endl;
                return value;
            } else {
                throw InvalidInput<std::string>(input);
            }
        } catch (EmptyInput<std::string> & emptyInput) {
            std::cout << "O campo não pode ser vazio!\n" << std::endl;
        } catch (InvalidInput<std::string> & invalidInput){
            std::cout << "Tipo de dados inválido!\n" << std::endl;
        }
    }
}
```

Thank you for your time!

Comment: Don't pass it an unsigned type?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In C++ arithmetic involving an `unsigned` type with *n* value bits, is guaranteed to be modulo 2^*n*. That means any result is wrapped back into the range 0 through 2^*n*-1, by adding or subtracting a suitable multiple of 2^*n*. This is so also in C.

So you need to check the input for minus sign, or add some other check.

By the way, your `if` with `>>` and `&&` produced some effect on my bad-code-meter. I can never remember the operator precedences for `>>` versus `&&`. I guess if it compiled it must be OK, though, since `>>` can't take a value right-hand-side. Checking... OK, but I'd use parentheses to clarify that.

Also, on the code structure, it would be a good idea to separate the interactive input thing from the checking of the input. E.g., can you use any of that code in a GUI program, with input from an edit field? No, not as it is...

Cheers & hth.,

Comment: Thanks for theoretical explanation. It helped me to understand the problem. Added the minus sign check and it works perfectly: `if (input[0] == '-' && std::numeric_limits<T>::min() == 0)`. About the bad-code, you were completly right, therefore I solved that too: `if ((sstream >> value) && (value >= min) && (value <= max))`. Indeed, it is more readable and leaves no room for doubt.

Comment: At last but not at least,on the code structure, I think that the solution would be separate the function into two, where one would get the user input and the other one, would validate it. I just have one noob doubt. Should I leave the try and catch block in the getter or handle completely the exceptions in the validater?

Comment: @renatorodrigues: it would be natural to keep the contract of the function you have, and that includes its response to exceptions. I envisioned more a refactoring like moving the code after `getline` and down to first `catch`, to a separate function that takes a string and produces a number (or throws if it cannot). Cheers,

Answer (score 1):

Alf has already answered this, but I had a couple of other thoughts.
Pull the code that gets the input out of the try block.  You're not catching any exceptions that it might throw, so it doesn't communicate the intent as well.  The try block should start right before the if (input.empty())...
Then pull all of the stuff in the try block into a single validate function.  This cleans up the code here.  For use in a GUI, though, you would want to create a function that just gets the input without validation and expose the validation function. Then the user could handle the validation exceptions as needed.  Although in this case, I don't see an advantage to using exceptions as opposed to simple error codes for the validation.

Hope this helps,