# Detecting negative number

Tags: c++

I have a code in which user has to pass > 0 number otherwise this code will throw. Using type of this arg as std::size_t doesn't work for the reason that negative numbers give large positive numbers. Is it good practice if I use signed type or are there other ways to enforce it?

```
void f(std::size_t number)
{
//if -1 is passed I'm (for obvious reason) get large positive number
}
```

Comment: This doesn't make any sense. size_t is unsigned and so is always a postive number and can't represent -1. You will have to use a signed type, or cast the size_t to a signed type, or test its top (sign) bit or something. It might help to know more about the wider functionality of this part of the code here...

Comment: What if the size is *really* a large positive number? ;)

Comment: @Paul: the issue does make sense: if you can call `f(-1)`, `f` will receive a `size_t` with the same bit representation as -1 which it will interpret as a huge unsigned value: it might not *be* -1 in that context, but it sure is a *problem*.

Comment: @Tony, exacgly, it doesn't make sense. There's definitely at least some confusion in the design if one can talk about "the  user has to pass >0 number" to something that takes an unsigned value... In other words, this isn't something that can be fixed by changing the code in a micro-sense. Take a step back, consider the design and the _meaning_ of the values being passed about.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A lot depends on what type of argument you imagine your clients trying to pass.  If they're passing int, and that's clearly big enough to hold the range of values you're going to use, then there's no practical advantage to using std::size_t - it won't enforce anything, and the way the issue manifests as an apparently huge number is simply more confusing.

BUT - it is good to use size_t anyway as it helps document the expectations of the API.

You clearly can't do a compile-time check for "> 0" against a run-time generated value, but can at least disambiguate negative inputs from intentional huge numbers ala

```
template <typename T>
void f(T t)
{
    if (!(t > 0))
        throw std::runtime_error("be positive!");

    // do stuff with t, knowing it's not -1 shoehorned into size_t...
    ...
}
```

But, if you are really concerned about this, you could provide overloads:

```
// call me please e.g. f(size_t(10));
void f(size_t);

// unimplemented (and private if possible)... 
// "want to make sure you realise this is unsigned: call f(size_t) explicitly
void f(int32_t);
void f(int64_t);
```

...then there's a compile-time error leading to the comments re caller explicitly providing a size_t argument (casting if necessary).  Forcing the client to provide an arg of size_t type is a pretty good way to make sure they're conscious of the issue.

Rin's got a good idea too - would work really well where it works at all (depends on there being an signed int type larger than size_t).  Go check it out....

EDIT - demonstration of template idea above...

```
#include <iostream>                                                             

template <typename T>                                                           
void f(T t)                                                                     
{                                                                               
    if (!(t > 0))                                                               
        std::cout << "bad call f(" << (int)t << ")\n";                               
    else                                                                        
        std::cout << "good f(" << (int)t << ")\n";                                   
}                                                                               

int main()                                                                      
{                                                                               
    f((char)-1);
    f((unsigned char)255);                                                     
}
```

Comment: thank you for your very interesting answer. I just can't make a sense out of your first example. What is it? is it a template function called f? if so what is the return type of it? And how am I suppose to understand (f > 0)? If you could please explain that to my murky brain I would be more than gratefull.

Comment: @There: sorry - left out the return type and the argument type! Careless. The idea's just that a template instantiation knows the type that the caller's actually passing in, so it can provide type-(and signed/unsigned is part of type)-aware verification. The `if (!(t>0) throw` just exits early if they's say called with int(-1), as the compiler still knows it's an int and won't confuse it with a legitimately huge size_t.

Comment: sorry still cannot grasp the concept of (f > 0). How compiler will know what value is passed to f? Would you be able to explain that to me, please?

Comment: @There: Back up to the "You clearly can't do a compile-time check for "> 0" against a run-time generated value, but can at least disambiguate negative inputs from intentional huge numbers ala...".  That's saying the compiler doesn't know the value at compile-time, but using a template it can know the type and generate type-specific code that at run-time will differentiate a negative signed number from a non-negative but huge signed number.  I suggest you just try it out - I'll append a little sample code to my answer.

Answer (score 5):

I don't think there's a definitive correct answer to this question. You can take an look to [Scott Meyers](http://www.aristeia.com/Papers/C++ReportColumns/sep95.pdf)'s opinion on the subject :

> One problem is that unsigned types
>   tend to decrease your ability to
>   detect common programming errors.
>   Another is that they often increase
>   the likelihood that clients of your
>   classes will use the classes
>   incorrectly.

In the end, the question to ask is really : do you need the extra possible values provided by the unsigned type ?

Comment: @Paul : changed to 'I don't think there's a definitive correct answer to this question'

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problems you're having: [Malfunctioning type-casting of string to unsigned int](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4151340/malfunctioning-type-casting-of-string-to-unsigned-int)

Since, in my case, I'm getting the input from the user, my approach was to read the data as a string and check its contents.

```
template <class T>
T getNumberInput(std::string prompt, T min, T max) {
    std::string input;
    T value;

    while (true) {
        try {
            std::cout << prompt;
            std::cin.clear();
            std::getline(std::cin, input);
            std::stringstream sstream(input);

            if (input.empty()) {
                throw EmptyInput<std::string>(input);
            } else if (input[0] == '-' && std::numeric_limits<T>::min() == 0) {
                throw InvalidInput<std::string>(input);
            } else if ((sstream >> value) && (value >= min) && (value <= max)) {
                std::cout << std::endl;
                return value;
            } else {
                throw InvalidInput<std::string>(input);
            }
        } catch (EmptyInput<std::string> & emptyInput) {
            std::cout << "O campo não pode ser vazio!\n" << std::endl;
        } catch (InvalidInput<std::string> & invalidInput){
            std::cout << "Tipo de dados invãlido!\n" << std::endl;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If your allowed value range for `number` allows it use the signed `std::ptrdiff_t` (like Alexey said).
Or use a library like [SafeInt](http://safeint.codeplex.com/) and have `f` declared something like this: `void f( SafeInt< std::size_t > i );` which throws if you'll call it with something like `f( -1 );`.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should wrap read-function to another function which purpose will be get `int` and validate it.

EDIT: Ok `int` was just first idea, so read and parse `string`

Comment: This only works if `sizeof(int) > sizeof(size_t)`, which is unlikely. For bullet-proof input you really need to read a string and do some validation on that before converting it to the required integer type.

Comment: @Paul R: if you happen to know there's a signed integer type larger than size_t (far from certain, esp for 64-bit apps), then you can simply use that.  Not a good general solution, but at least an example where's Rin's idea could work.

Comment: @Tony: yes, this will work in *some* cases, but it's not very portable

Comment: @Paul R: I think you'll find there are no good solutions to this one... still good to enumerate the options.

Answer (score 0):

Fisrt solution

```
void f(std::ptrdiff_t number) {
   if (number < 0) throw;
}
```

Second solution

```
void f(std::size_t number) {
   if (number > std::numeric_limits<std::size_t>::max()/2) throw;
}
```

Comment: Neither of these allows the full range of valid input for size_t though.

Comment: And the second solution is plain wrong: what if I want to pass a *valid* number that is greater than std::numeric_limits<std::size_t>/2?

Comment: @Simone. And what if I want to pass a number that is greater than `std::numeric_limits<std::size_t>::max()`? Use the type larger than `size_t` and `ptrdiff_t`. For 32-bit compiler use something like `__int64`. For 64-bit compiler use something like `__int128`.

Answer (score 0):

This is one of the situations where you cannot really do much. The compiler usually gives out a warning when converting signed to unsigned data-types, so you will have to trust the caller to heed that warning.

Answer (score 0):

You could test this using bitwise operation, such as the following:

```
void f(std::size_t number)
{
   if(number & (0x1L << (sizeof(std::size_t) * 8 - 1)) != 0)
   {
       // high bit is set. either someone passed in a negative value,
       // or a very large size that we'll assume is invalid.

       // error case goes here
   }
   else
   {
       // valid value
   }
}
```

This code assumes 8-bit bytes. =)

Yes, large values will fail, but you could document that they are not allowed, if you really need to protect against this.

Who is using this API? Rather than using a solution like this, I would recommend that they fix their code. =) I would think that the "normal" best practice would be for callers to use size_t, and have their compilers complain loudly if they try to put signed values into them.

Answer (score 0):

I had to think about this question a little, and this is what I would do.

If your function has the responsability to throw an exception if you pass a negative number, then your function's signature should accept a **signed** integer number. That's because if you accept an unsigned number, you won't ever be able to tell unambiguosly if a number is negative and you won't be able to throw an exception. IOW, you want complain to your assignment of throwing exception.

You should establish what is an acceptable input range and use a signed integer large enough to fully contain that range.

Comment: Be careful not to confuse > 0 with non-negative :-).  Your reasoning's sound if such a larger-than-size_t signed int exists (indeed, Rin answered with the same idea a while back).

Comment: "There is nothing..." didn't clarified if *every* value in the range 0 .. std::numeric_limits<size_t>::max() is acceptable as input. If that's the case, I'd use a big integer library given the function's requisite. I don't really get your first statement, anyway..